# HTMLUnit : super slow execution?

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

I have been using HTMLUnit . It suits my requirements well. But it seems to be extremely slow.
for example : I have automated the following scenario using HTMLUnit

```
Goto Google page
Enter some text
Click on the search button
Get the title of the results page
Click on the first result.
```

Code :

```
long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
WebClient webClient=createWebClient();
WebRequest webReq=new WebRequest(new URL("http://google.lk"));

HtmlPage googleMainPage=webClient.getPage(webReq);
HtmlTextInput searchTextField=(HtmlTextInput) googleMainPage.getByXPath("//input[@name='q']").get(0);
HtmlButton searchButton=(HtmlButton) googleMainPage.getByXPath("//button[@name='btnK']").get(0);

searchTextField.type("Sri Lanka");
System.out.println("Text typed!");
HtmlPage googleResultsPage= searchButton.click();
System.out.println("Search button clicked!");

System.out.println("Title : " + googleResultsPage.getTitleText());

HtmlAnchor firstResultLink=(HtmlAnchor) googleResultsPage.getByXPath("//a[@class='l']").get(0);
HtmlPage firstResultPage=firstResultLink.click();
System.out.println("First result clicked!");

System.out.println("Title : " + firstResultPage.getTitleText());
//System.out.println(firstResultPage.asText());
long t2=System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff=t2-t1;
System.out.println("Time elapsed : "  + milliSecondsToHrsMinutesAndSeconds(diff));

webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

It works 100% well. But it takes  3 minutes,41 seconds

I guess the reason for the slow execution is validating each and every element on the page.

My question is how to reduce the execution time of HTMLUnit ? is there any way to disable validations on webpages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please find the updated code.

Comment: Disabling JS support will make it waaaaayy faster

Comment: try to access only one link and see whether it takes time

Comment: Disabling JavaScript is not an option!

Comment: Takes 25s on my computer. Are you short of memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the current htmlUnit 2.13, setting options is slightly different from what maxmax has provided:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);//if you don't need css
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);//if you don't need js
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://XXX.xxx.xx");
...
```

In my own test, this is 8 times faster than the default options.(Note that this could be webpage-dependent)

Comment: Disabling JS will always result in faster execution. However, the OP mentioned `Disabling JavaScript is not an option!` :)

Comment: What does OP stands for? Do you mean that JS shouldn't be disabled?

Comment: I mean, the asker added in a comment to the question that disabling JS is not an option

Comment: Oh, I missed it. I was intended to improve maxmax's answer, and paid too little attention to the original question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

- Be sure to use latest htmlunit version (2.9). I had a performance boost from previous version.

I get your example done within 20s, or 40s depending options i set. As i can't see the webClient initialisation, i guess maybe it could be the problem.

Here's my initialisation for a 20s treatment :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    client.setTimeout(60000);
    client.setRedirectEnabled(true);
    client.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.setCssEnabled(false);
    client.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend also to set a time limit to the javascript:

```
   client.setJavaScriptTimeout(30000); //e.g. 30s
```