# Why WebClient in HtmlUnit consuming more execution time?

Tags: java, htmlunit

Im using HtmlUnit to grab content of web page (having javascript)

```
   Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch().start();
   final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
   webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setDoNotTrackEnabled(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
   webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
   webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
   webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);
   webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(900);

   System.out.println("1.0 : " + timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
   final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
   System.out.println(page.getWebResponse().getLoadTime());
   System.out.println("1.1 : " + timer.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

then the result i got is like this

```
   1.0 : 2
   707
   1.1 : 8003
```

Why webclient consuming more time (more than webresponse load time)? how can i reduce that time?

Comment: i refered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442803/htmlunit-super-slow-execution) as well.

Comment: i found that time increasing because of time consuming for javascript execution. Is there any way to reduce it?