# HTMLUnit for Android extremly slow

Tags: android, htmlunit

Hello i want to build an app with htmlunit for android (Android Studio).
If I try to cget the page of youtube this tooks a lot of seconds (over 10). So that is too slow for user experience... other sites are slow too

build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.htmlunit', name: 'htmlunit3-android', version: '3.3.0'
```

my simple code

```
   HtmlPage htmlPage;

    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        htmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.youtube.com/");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [HTMLUnit : super slow execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442803/htmlunit-super-slow-execution)

According to the accepted answer of the duplicate question, you can disable Javascript for faster execution

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);//if you don't need js
```

But if you need JavaScript to be enabled then you may try adding a timeout to request

```
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(30000)
```

Comment: thanks, i use HtmlUnit, because Jsoup can't javascript. I want to webscrap some sites. With setting the timeout nothing changes.

Comment: I am getting a lot of these erros in Logcat. Perhaps here is a problem? But I don't know why: 2023-07-01 14:50:24.006 11570-11579 oid.persistenc          com.example.android.persistence      I  Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 39878 in int org.htmlunit.cssparser.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)

Comment: @Dan same here, were you able to fix that?

Comment: No I don't have any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do

```
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(false);
```

Comment: thanks but with that it's still too slow for an app.

Comment: Please open an issue in github and let's discuss it there....

Comment: did you tried my code? how long takes it? no errors in logcat?